# Adverse effects of reduced food variety on microbiome

Tags: space-colonization, food, brain

We often see, in Sci-fi, food being produced from, say, algae or yeast. What could be the effect of such a limited diet on the gut microbiome? Would there be any believable side-effect that would have an influence on the brain?

I'm thinking of a first colony on Mars where people start behaving strangely, but I'm not sure how believable it would be to have them really affected, except to make them more, or less, autistic.

EDIT: I'm looking more into lack of certain bacteria than pathological elements.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: Well, food without proper texture makes people crazy after a while. All early long duration astronauts said so.

Comment: Part of the problem of answering this well is that we don't have a particularly good understanding of our microbiomes to start with...

Comment: @Starfish: Indeed. I was just hoping for some ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

**Loss of gut bacteria diversity.**

Same as vegetarians loose the ability to digest meat after not eating meat for years. If their diet were to change, they would be ill prepared to process it after a lifetime of having always the same food.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would depend on the nutrient density of the engineered vat-grown food.  It would certainly be consistent which would favor the microbiome beasties that were adapted to scavenge off the digestive byproducts produced by the humans consuming it.  @Gustava outlined, some would die off.  Others might flourish.

But since nature abhors a vacuum, if there was a surplus of potential food not being consumed then natural genetic variance would eventually fill that gap in the biome with mutation derived from current flora and fauna.

Fevered competition for food always seems to give rise to creatures that will fill their bellies in some other way, and by doing so they thrive until that nook of the food chain gets packed with competition.  Darwin's finches and  hummingbirds demonstrated that principle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of possibilities, from gut poisoning to completely nothing. It all depends on the amount grown, and in what locality to one another. If they are all grown in, lets say, one building, with thousands of cultures being grown at once, then you could be screwed in a variety of ways. If there is an outbreak of any infections in the food, than due to it being only grown in one area, the infection will likely spread quickly, infecting the food with whatever disease it contains. If that is your only food source, then your colony could be quickly screwed over. 
There could've been a minor infection, that sent spores into the brain that clotted up the neuron connections. The connections would've been flooded with the spores, and subsequently suffocated. Various brain damage could take place, from minor IQ changes to coma and motor skill loss or destruction.
All in all, it depends on the setting and the variables.